# How can I know what is the binary value I receive in a tcp socket?

Tags: shell, tcp, socket, binary

in a socket created in the following way: `nc -k -l 3111` I receive this message:

```
�1100B2346541A8E080140000000000000020200000000000561500062820004082043419062513414319095912152201101200004100591206099104109000001716375413200 ...
```

The first two characters are the binary data that I want to know in order to send the answer.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Pipe the output of your `nc` command into some program that will show the values of the individual bytes of output, instead of just sending those bytes to the terminal which will treat the bytes as printable characters.  For example:

```
nc -k -l 3111 | od -tx1
```

or:

```
nc -k -l 3111 | hexdump -C
```

Answer (score 0):

`cut -b N` or `cut --bytes=N` (GNU `cut`) will give you the first N bytes of a stream.